# Keep stealing from me

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> Steal my completeness and I'm still productive.
>
> Steal my productivity and I'm still normal.
>
> Steal my normality and I'm still metric.
>
> Steal my metric and I'm still open.

What am I?

Comment: (rot 13) Guvf zhfg or fbzr xvaq bs zngurzngvpny fcnpr evtug? What happens if I take away your openness? :-P

Comment: @Eric Steal my openness and I'll be killed...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must be talking about a

> [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)

Steal my completeness and I'm still productive.

> Every Hilbert space is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) meaning that every Cauchy sequence has a limit in the space. Even if we remove the restriction of completeness to define a much larger set of topological spaces we still have a space which has an **inner product**.

Steal my productivity and I'm still normal.

> If we then remove the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) from our topological space we are still left with a space on which a norm is defined - a [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space).

Steal my normality and I'm still metric.

> If we were to remove the norm from our space we would be left with a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) which is just a topological space endowed with a notion of distance.

Steal my metric and I'm still open.

> If we remove the metric from our space we are left with a pure [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space). Topological spaces are often defined via a collection of open sets with certain properties and, within this construction, the entire space itself is also an open set.

This diagram I took from Wikipedia explains it quite well

> [image]
>  with the caveat that Hilbert spaces constitute another circle contained within inner product spaces.